# Check if character 'x' comes before character 'y' in a string Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, validation, email

I'm making an email validation system for one of my projects and all was working fine until I bumped into the error that if the email followed the structure:

> username.domain@domain-ext

then it would return TRUE.
So is there a way to check if the '@' comes before the '.' in vanilla javascript?

here is the code:

```js
    function validate ( element ) {
      if( element.indexOf ( '@' ) > -1 && element.indexOf ( '.' ) > -1 ){
        //checks if there is anything between '@' and '.'
        var domain_name = element.substring(
          element.lastIndexOf("@") + 1,
          element.lastIndexOf(".")
        );
        if (domain_name != '')
        {
          //checks if there is anything before the '@'
          var username = element.split('@')[0];
          if (username != '') {
            //checks if there is anything after the '.'
            var emailsplit = element.split('.');
            var domain = emailsplit[emailsplit.length - 1];
            if (domain != '')
            {
              return true;
            }
            else {
              return false;
            }
          }
          else {
            return false;
          }
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    console.log('username@domain.com : ' + validate('username@domain.com'));
    console.log('@domain.com : ' + validate('@domain.com'));
    console.log('username@.com : ' + validate('username@.com'));
    console.log('username@domain. : ' + validate('username@domain.'));
    console.log('usernamedomaincom : ' + validate('usernamedomaincom'));
    console.log('username.domain@com : ' + validate('username.domain@com'));
```

Comment: _"Check if character 'x' comes before character 'y'"_: `str.indexOf('x') < str.indexOf('y')` but you probably need `str.indexOf('@') < str.lastIndexOf('.')`

Comment: `.` are allowed in email names though

Comment: _"So is there a way to check if the '@' comes before the '.'"_ - You already know the solution: `if( element.indexOf ( '@' ) > -1 && element.indexOf ( '.' ) > -1 )` - So what's the actual problem?

Comment: @Andreas as you can see in the console.log statements, the last one returns true even though that is an invalid email

Comment: I haven't said that this is the answer to your problem. But it contains all you need for the answer. It just needs some adaptions -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Your question doesn't describe your actual problem. You don't want to know if `'@'` comes before the first `'.'`. You want to know if `'@'` comes before the last `'.'`. That can be answered using [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Comment: technically, the last one is a valid email, the domain doesn't have to have a dot, it can be a local network domain

Comment: @vanowm Technically the last one is a valid email address but a public website usually shouldn't allow such addresses.

Comment: @vanowm Yes, but on my website I would rather the users do not use local network domains though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to add 1 more if statement using the lastIndexOf. Thank you @jabaa

```js
    function validate ( element ) {
      if( element.indexOf ( '@' ) > -1 && element.indexOf ( '.' ) > -1 ){
        if ( element.indexOf('@') < element.lastIndexOf('.') )
        {
          //checks if there is anything between '@' and '.'
          var domain_name = element.substring(
            element.lastIndexOf("@") + 1,
            element.lastIndexOf(".")
          );
          if (domain_name != '')
          {
            //checks if there is anything before the '@'
            var username = element.split('@')[0];
            if (username != '') {
              //checks if there is anything after the '.'
              var emailsplit = element.split('.');
              var domain = emailsplit[emailsplit.length - 1];
              if (domain != '')
              {
                return true;
              }
              else {
                return false;
              }
            }
            else {
              return false;
            }
          }
          else {
            return false;
          }
        }
        else {
          return false
        }
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    console.log('username@domain.com : ' + validate('username@domain.com'));
    console.log('@domain.com : ' + validate('@domain.com'));
    console.log('username@.com : ' + validate('username@.com'));
    console.log('username@domain. : ' + validate('username@domain.'));
    console.log('usernamedomaincom : ' + validate('usernamedomaincom'));
    console.log('username.domain@com : ' + validate('username.domain@com'));
```